# Looping a file writer

Tags: java, loops, iteration

I'm building a *relativley* simple stock system to account for books I own in a file, however I'm having trouble iterating the inputs.

Here are my imports:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
```

and the globals:

```
private static File myFile = new File("libraryList.txt");
private static ArrayList<String> bookTitles = new ArrayList<String>();
private static Scanner inputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
```

So the array "bookTitles" stores the title, author, ISBN and genre of a book - all of which have inputs that work. I can input all of the information for one book - and it'll be written successfully.

The main issue comes when attempting to write a second book in.

My "add another book" loop works, however it won't write any further than just the first book entered.

```
System.out.println("Would you like to add another book? Y/N");
            String addAnother = inputScanner.nextLine(); //assigns the answer for addAnother to the variable
            if (addAnother.equals("N")) {
                addNewBook = false; //if they don't want to add another, end the loop.
                WriteToFile();
            }
```

same goes for the file writer - it all works fine, but only for the first iteration.

```
public static void WriteToFile() {
    try {
        FileWriter myWriter = new FileWriter(myFile.getName(), true); //True means append to file contents, False means overwrite
        System.out.println("This is the contents of the file:");
        myWriter.write(""); //makes a space between each book
        myWriter.write(bookTitles.get(0)+(" ")); // adds the current list to the file
        myWriter.write(bookTitles.get(1)+(" "));
        myWriter.write(bookTitles.get(2)+(" "));
        myWriter.write(bookTitles.get(3)+("\n\n"));
        myWriter.close();
        System.out.println("Successfully wrote to the file.");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("An error occurred.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I'm aware that the issue stems from me only accessing units 0-3 from the array, however I can't come up with an iteration that works properly with the rest of my code - everything I've attempted thus far has just broken.

Here's the pastebin link for the full code:

https://pastebin.com/BiXBuu88

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have identified the issue correctly, in your `WriteToFile` method you are only adding a single book from your `bookTitles` list to the file, more precisely you are only adding the first book that was input in the current run.

You would have to change that code into a loop that iterates over the whole `bookTitles` list. Since you save all the data sequentially into the List, and since you know that you have exactly 4 units of data per book, you can use a `for` loop with an index increment of `4`. Then instead of accessing indices at `0, 1, 2, 3` you access indices at `i, i+1, i+2, i+3` inside the loop.

Since the index increment is `4` this means that the indices in your loop iterations will be the following:

```java
0, 1, 2, 3 // for the 1st book
4, 5, 6, 7 // for the 2nd book
// ...
size-4, size-4 + 1, size-4 + 2, size-4 + 3 // for the last book
```

In the original code this then becomes

```java
    public static void WriteToFile() {
        try {
            FileWriter myWriter = new FileWriter(myFile.getName(), true); //True means append to file contents, False means overwrite
            // adds the current list to the file
            for (int i = 0; i < bookTitles.size(); i += 4) {
                myWriter.write(bookTitles.get(i)+(" "));
                myWriter.write(bookTitles.get(i+1)+(" "));
                myWriter.write(bookTitles.get(i+2)+(" "));
                myWriter.write(bookTitles.get(i+3)+("\n\n"));
            }
            myWriter.close();
            System.out.println("Successfully wrote to the file.");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("An error occurred.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```